# Getting images based on tags

Tags: java, rest, mariadb, parent-child

I have this small hobby project. The goal is to diplay images. For each image there is a number of children called tags.

My problem is get images based on a tag and create date.

I use a

- mariaDb,
- tomcat 9
- hibernate 5.6.9.Final

I have a java based REST service and an agular frontend.

These are my two entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class ImageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "photoalbum_image_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "photoalbum_image_seq", sequenceName = "photoalbum_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "imageYear")
    private String imageYear;
    @Column(name = "imageMonth")
    private String imageMonth;
    @Column(name = "imageDay")
    private String imageDay;
    @Column(name = "imagePath")
    private String imagePath;
    @Column(name = "checksum")
    private String checksum;
    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createdate;
    @Column(name = "mediatype")
    private String mediaType;

    @Column(name = "internetpath")
    private String internetpath;
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private double longitude;
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MetaEntity> metas = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TagEntity> tags = new LinkedList<>();

    Getters and setters.
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class TagEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "photoalbum_tags_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "photoalbum_tags_seq", sequenceName = "photoalbum_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id", nullable = false)
    private ImageEntity image;
    
    Getter and setters.

}
```

This is my DDL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE photoalbum_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE image(
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  imageYear varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  imageMonth varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  imageDay varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  imagePath varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  checksum varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  createdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  mediatype varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  internetpath varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  longitude DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  latitude DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT image_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;


CREATE TABLE tag (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  image_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tags_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=621396 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE meta (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  image_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  metaKey varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT meta_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=621396 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="PhotoalbumPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Persistence provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Entity classes -->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/photoalbum" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect"/>
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******"/>
            <!-- property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/ -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/ -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/ -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

```
    public static List<ImageEntity> getimages(int count, Date startDate, Date endDate, String tag) {

        List<ImageEntity> res = em.createQuery(
                "select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where  img.createdate > :start and t.value = 'v50'",
                ImageEntity.class).setParameter("start", startDate).getResultList();
        return res;

    }
```

I have googeld an got a lot of result where they kind of solutions.

One of the "solutions" is the folloing.

https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-hibernate-hql-query-to-get-parent-children-based-on-childid/

```
select p from Parent p join p.childList c
    where p.name = 'John' and c.favoriteColor = 'blue'
```

I replace the Parent with ImageEntity child with TagEntity.

The following 2 will work.

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where t.value = 'v50'
```

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where  img.createdate > :start
```

The following will NOT work.

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where  img.createdate > :start and t.value = 'v50'
```

As you can see if I use only 1 "criteria" it works. If I use both, it will not work.

I feel I'm out of options.

I you have any questions, I do what I can to answer.

Update.

- I have 666 images in my database.
- I have 1560 tags in my database.
- The date send is 1970-01-01 and it get converted before I use it use it in a query

With the following sql i get 1560 results.

```
select count(*) from image i 
inner join tag t 
on i.id = t.image_id;
```

With de folowing sql I get 44 results.

```
select count(*) from image i 
inner join tag t 
on i.id = t.image_id
where t.value = 'v50';
```

While debugging I get 44 results when using the following jql/hql

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where t.value = 'v50'
```

With the following jql/hql I get 707 results.

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where img.createdate > : start
```

With the following jql/hql I get an empty array as results.

```
select img from ImageEntity img join fetch img.tags t where img.createdate  >: start
```

As before, if you need more information, I'll try to give you more information.
If I could i would upload the complete src and pom. If anyone know how to do that, please tell me.

Comment: I would expect a syntax error here `fetch img.tags t`; please explain what you think that means.

Comment: Nor does this look right:  `>:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it matters but I now use tomcat 10.1

Changed query to the following

```
List<ImageEntity> imgEntities = em.createQuery(
                "select a from ImageEntity a  join a.tags t where t.value = :tag and  a.createdate > :start and a.createdate < :end order by a.createdate",ImageEntity.class)
.setParameter("start", startDate)
.setParameter("end", endDate)
.setParameter("tag", "vecka 42")
.setMaxResults(count)
.getResultList();
```

This results in a list of images. Note that I use a different tag. Using tag = v50 results in an empty list.

Have to check my DB to see why v50 dose work.

Any way the query seams to work.

Answer (score 0):

If both queries are working well and return results are as you expected, then definitely the problem in the final query with 2 conditions.

The problem may be related to:

1. There are no images with tag `v50` younger than specified data. Just check it in the DB.
2. Please take into account, that `createdate` also stored time 'hh:mm:ss' for the date. And may be you need to reset the `:start` date to the start of the day before passing it to the query.

NOTE: If you provide more info, than help may be more useful :)

Comment: Thank you,@eg04lt3r for reading and giving feedback. I hope I given answer to some of you comments.